# Config Error: Section or group name 'system.web.extensions' is already defined

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, web-config

Afternoon All,

I have spent a good chunk of my time on the internet tryiong to solve the below issue but im getting myself a little confused. I am new to .net and im working in VS 2010.

Im trying to get a simple calendar to work with an image and a text box. I have the AjaxControlToolkit.dll (Version 3.5).  I the following error when trying to get this calender to work:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection' to type 'System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection'.

Here is my .aspx code (Which has a blue line right at the top of the page which states that there is a system.we.extensions  error, but i already have this in my web config file?)

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default2" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

  <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>

<div>
     <asp:ImageButton runat="Server" ID="ImageButton1" ImageUrl="~/images/calendar.gif" 
            AlternateText="Click here to display calendar" /> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    <cc1:calendarextender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" 
             TargetControlID="TextBox1" PopupButtonID="ImageButton1">
    </cc1:calendarextender>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my web config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings/>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestConn" connectionString="Data Source=Server1;Initial Catalog=CatalogName;User ID=UserID;Password=Password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
        <compilation debug="true">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"></add>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"></add>
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<httpModules></httpModules>
<pages>
      <controls>
          <add namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="cc1" />
          <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" 
               assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
          <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" 
               assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </controls>
 </pages>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Many Thanks in advance.

Regards
Betty

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the System.Web.Extensions section twice:

```
 <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" 
               assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
 <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" 
               assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

Remove one of them.

After you do that, you'll probably have some compilation errors. Just adjust the using statements to point to the appropriate namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the response but i have removed the following tagPrefix but i still have the same error?      <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>

Comment: @Betty Try removing the assembly attribute from the one that's left; in other words, just use this: `<add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" />`